# code from java to .net (c#)

Tags: c#, java, .net

ich have a little Problem to write a .net code. I have an example in java and want to convert it to .net!!

Java Code:

```
String url = "https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/reportdownload?__rd="
    + reportDefinitionId;
 HttpURLConnection urlConn = 
    (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
urlConn.setRequestMethod ("GET");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth="
    + user.getRegisteredAuthToken());
if (user.getClientCustomerId() != null) {
  urlConn.setRequestProperty("clientCustomerId", user.getClientCustomerId());
} else if (user.getClientEmail() != null) {
  urlConn.setRequestProperty("clientEmail", user.getClientEmail());
} else {
  urlConn.setRequestProperty("clientEmail", user.getEmail());
}
urlConn.connect();
copyStream(urlConn.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(
    new File(outputFileName)));
```

Thank you for Help!!
If you need more Information, please ask me
Alexo

Comment: [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) for the lazy...

Comment: You don't have to do his work. It's enough to give him pointers as the answers below. Why scare away new users? Just show them how it works here at SO..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this post: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_22691600.html

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `WebClient` class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx